# Linux fork, execve - no wait zombies

Tags: linux, fork, exec

In Linux & C, will not waiting (waitpid) for a fork-execve launched process create zombies?
What is the correct way to launch a new program (many times) without waiting and without resource leaks?
It would also be launched from a 2nd worker thread.
Can the first program terminate first cleanly if launched programs have not completed?

Additional: In my case I have several threads that can fork-execve processes at ANY TIME and THE SAME TIME -
1) Some I need to wait for completion and want to report any errors codes with waitpid
2) Some I do not want to block the thread and but would like to report errors
3) Some I don't want to wait and don't care about the outcome and could run after the program terminates

For #2, should I have to create an additional thread to do waitpid ?
For #3, should I do a fork-fork-execve and would ending the 1st fork cause the 2nd process to get cleaned up (no zombie) separately via init ?

Additional: I've read briefly (not sure I understand all) about using nohup, double fork, setgpid(0,0), signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN).
Doesn't global signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN) have too many side effects like getting inherited (or maybe not) and preventing monitoring other processes you do want to wait for ?
Wouldn't relying on init to cleanup resources leak while the program continues to run (weeks in my case)?

Comment: You should set the `SIGCHLD` signal disposition to default with the `SA_NOCLDWAIT` flag, instead of ignoring `SIGCHLD`. `sa.sa_handler = SIG_DFL;
        sa.sa_flags = SA_NOCLDWAIT; ... if(sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa, 0) == -1) error_out()`

Answer (score 0):

> In Linux & C, will not waiting (waitpid) for a fork-execve launched process create zombies?

Yes, they become zombies after death.

> What is the correct way to launch a new program (many times) without waiting and without resource leaks? It would also be launched from a 2nd worker thread.

Set `SIGCHLd` to `SIG_IGN`.

> Can the first program terminate first cleanly if launched programs have not completed?

Yes, orphaned processes will be adopted by [init](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init).

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure SIGCHLD SIG_IGN is way to go (I updated my question). I've been trying to track down why my program starts to misbehave after many hours, many execs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up keeping an array of just the fork-exec'd pids I did not wait for (other fork-exec'd pids do get waited on) and periodically scanned the list using
waitpid( pids[xx], &status, WNOHANG ) != 0
which gives me a chance report outcome and avoid zombies.
I avoided using global things like signal handlers that might affect other code elsewhere.

It seemed a bit messy.

I suppose that fork-fork-exec would be an alternative to asynchronously monitor the other program's completion by the first fork, but then the first fork needs cleanup.

In Windows, you just keep a handle to the process open if you want to check status without worry of pid reuse, or close the handle if you don't care what the other process does.
(In Linux, there seems no way for multiple threads or processes to monitor the status of the same process safely, only the parent process-thread can, but not my issue here.)